# UPDATE mysql fields using a value from a SELECT statement with a condition from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that are related to each other.

One is **user_registration** and the other is **user_group**.

Inside the user_registration table, I have the fields:

- id
- id_user
- date_begin
- date_end

And **user_group**:

- id
- id_user
- id_group

I have just tried to learn simple join statements to select some records based on their group id like:

```
SELECT a.id_user, a.date_begin, a.date_end, b.id_group
FROM user_registration as a
INNER JOIN user_group as b
ON a.id_user=b.id_user
WHERE b.id_group = '14'
```

But right now, what I am trying to do is to set the *date_end* to be the same as the *date_begin* where in the id_group of the records will be the same.

---

I already got it. This did the trick although I am not sure this is the most efficient way as I am still learning MySQL.

```
UPDATE user_registration AS a
INNER JOIN user_group AS b ON a.id_user = b.id_user
SET a.date_end = a.date_begin
WHERE b.id_group = '14'
```

Comment: update queries can use joined tables as data sources.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what table the date_end and date_begin are compared to the id_group? Looking at the user_group table I do not see a date_begin or date_end so not understanding what you are looking for? Then I see this billing_user_period table but no schema for that?

Comment: @Shawn, it was supposed to be  user_registration instead of billing_user_period. Please see my edit. I have also tried to create a query but I am having an error.

Comment: @drifter that query is correct. You should choose to answer your own question with it so this question is resolved. You can also do all groups by not including the where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on the edit above, this accomplished what I was trying to do.

```
UPDATE user_registration AS a
INNER JOIN user_group AS b ON a.id_user = b.id_user
SET a.date_end = a.date_begin
WHERE b.id_group = '14'
```

Assuming that 14 is a group id.

I am not that certain about its efficiency though. I still have to do more readings and learn more about it.

Comment: Click the checkmark so this question is resolved :-)

Comment: @Shawn, it says I can only accept my own answer in 2 days. A bit of a bummer but I'm happy I was able to solve it on my own. :)